# What is difference between these bootstrapping methods in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

Could not find the difference between these two.
Does this make sense to keep any of these to bootstrap my angular app?

```
angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);
```

or

```
angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
```

Comment: Maybe AngularAMD was used in previous versions? I think it should only be used in very specific applications. It is better to use `ng-bind` instead of {{}} and use `ng-cloak` class to hide portions of the app which might take long to load. Always try to resolve the maximum and set variable that can be set before it bootstraps into `.config`

Comment: Used angularAMD to make application fully modular.

Answer (score 1):

`angularAMD` is an utility that facilitates the use of RequireJS in AngularJS applications supporting on-demand loading of 3rd party modules such as `angular-ui`.

And this module provides you

```
define(['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
    var app = angular.module(app_name, ['webapp']);
    ... // Setup app here. E.g.: run .config with $routeProvider
    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

Where as `angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);` [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) is in build angular method to boostrap application.

Use any of it but stick with one only.